# I want unique mobile numbers and count from comma delim String variable

Tags: java, string

```
String mobiles="1234567890,0987654321,1234567890,1122334455"
```

I need output as

```
mobiles = "1234567890,0987654321,1122334455";
int count = 3;
```

I am coding in java.

Comment: Use regex to check for comma and take a count variable and increment it each time comma is matched.

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I think, the regex you are looking for is ","

Comment: @TheLostMind I think I mean `.distinct()` like this `String result = Arrays.stream(mobiles.split(","))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you ton read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently your question seems like you're asking us to do your job. Unfortunatly this is not the goal of this site. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50249189/edit) your question, to show us what you've done/try, what research effort you've done. Detail more what problem you are facing. You don't know how to use `split()` ? you don't know how to use regex ? what is your exact problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by @YSF_L is correct
`String mobiles = Arrays.stream(mmobiles.split(",")) .distinct() .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
String[] mcounts = mobiles.split(",");
     int Count = mcounts.length;`